# How do I modify a refrigerator water line to add a shut off valve and flexible pipe?

Tags: water, refrigerator, pipe, valve, copper

I recently bought a house and bought a new fridge to go with it. The copper pipe that connects to the fridge water has a shut off valve underneath the house and is extremely inconvenient to access. The copper pipe is also fairly long once out of the wall (could probably stretch a good 4' - 5' if it was pulled straight) and once hooked up it would be hard to push the fridge back without damaging/kinking the pipe.

Is it possible for me to cut the pipe to around 1' or so in length and attach some sort of flexible pipe that would have a shut off valve on it?

If so does anyone have any good instructions on how to do it/materials needed?

Comment: Usually fridges are installed with soft tempered copper which is flexible - are you sure they used ridged copper pipe?

Comment: The coil of flexible copper pipe is there for a reason, it allows you to pull the fridge out for cleaning and maintenance.

Comment: Search for "brass compression fitting." That will allow you to go from copper piping to NPT. From there you can go anywhere.

Comment: @Steven and Tester101 the copper pipe is flexible, but there's just too much of it and I won't be able to push the fridge all the way back without being extremely careful and some help. I figured if I'm going to cut it in order for the fridge to fit in, I might as well see if I can cut it all the way back and add something that will be more flexible and have a shut off valve in a more convenient location.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution is fairly simple. Cut the copper tubing about a foot from the floor and install an inline valve. Use a compression coupler type valve and run the remainder with plastic tubing. Food grade 1/4"  plastic tubing will fit well on a 1/4" compression or graduated/clamp fitting. These fitting are available at building box stores or RV stores.